# How is the internal hom in $\mathsf{sSet}/\mathcal C$ defined?

Tags: simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

Fix a simplicial set $\mathcal C$. We have a category of simplicial sets over $\mathcal C$, denoted by $\mathsf{sSet}/\mathcal C$. This is supposed to have an internal hom, denoted $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathcal C}(X, Y)$ for every two objects $X \to \mathcal C$ and $Y \to \mathcal C$ of $\mathsf{sSet}/\mathcal C$. How is this defined precisely? What are the $n$-simplices in $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathcal C}(X, Y)$?

What I know is that this should satisfy naturally the following equation, if $A \to \mathcal C$ is a third object of $\mathsf{sSet}/\mathcal C$:

$$ \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{sSet}/\mathcal C}(A \times_{\mathcal C}X \to \mathcal C, Y\to \mathcal C) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{sSet}/\mathcal C}(A \to \mathcal C, \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathcal C}(X, Y)\to \mathcal C)$$

Can we use this in some way to identify the simplices of $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathcal C}(X, Y)$? Also, [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwialNuymq_2AhUTSPEDHQ4JCNsQFnoECAQQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de%2Fcisinski%2FCatLR.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0U7eP5s9bHJmrPP3ILu9qK), at page 208, this object is introduced, and it is claimed that morphisms $A \to \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathcal C}(X, Y)$ over $\mathcal C$ correspond to morphisms $A \times_{\mathcal C} X \to A \times_{\mathcal C} Y$ over $A$. I think this is equivalent to the equality that I have written above, since it should be true that

$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{sSet}/A}(A \times_{\mathcal C}X \to A, A \times_{\mathcal C} Y\to \mathcal A)\cong  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{sSet}/\mathcal C}(A \times_{\mathcal C}X \to \mathcal C, Y\to \mathcal C),$$

but I am not sure, is this correct?

Comment: You can use the Yoneda lemma. Consider morphisms from arbitrary $\Delta^n \to C$ into the internal hom.

Comment: @ZhenLin I tried to, because in principle the Yoneda lemma could help me identify the $n$-simplices as $(\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathcal C}(X, Y))_n\cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{sSet}}(\Delta^n, \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X, Y)),$ but the product-hom adjunction just gives me $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{sSet}/\mathcal C}(\Delta^n\to \mathcal C, \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathcal C}(X, Y)\to \mathcal C)$ and not $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{sSet}}(\Delta^n, \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathcal C}(X, Y)).$

Comment: That’s not a problem. You get the latter by taking the disjoint union of the former.

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't think I get what you mean. Disjoint union over what?

Comment: Disjoint union over the different morphisms $\Delta^n \to C$, of course. That's how you eliminate the dependency on it.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, I get it now, sorry, it was easy.

Answer (score 0):

Soory. I only wrote link. I add some explain the definition of this simplicial structure.

You can find the definition of internal hom in sSet/C in https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04815 Section.2.1.

First, for any $X,Y \in sSet_{/ S}$, define $Map_{/ S}(X,Y) := sSet(X,Y) \times_{sSet(X,S)} \Delta^0$.

Second, for any $X \in sSet_{/S}, K \in sSet$, define tensor $X \otimes K := X \times K$, and consider $X \times K \to X \to S$ as the object in $sSet_{/S}$.

Finally, define cotensor $X^K := sSet(K,X) \times_{sSet(K,S)} \{S\}$.

The condition of isomorphisms in the definition of simplicial model categories can be checked by definition.